# Adapter constructor of own implementation is not accepting hashMap.values()

Tags: java, android, hashmap

I implemented my own `Adapter` from `ArrayAdapter<>`. Within the constructor I am using a HashMap which gets **UUID** as a key and another random class called **Room**. Basically, it is a SmartHome app that has Rooms which carry Devices (fyi). However, the implementation of the constructor for `RoomAdapter` (found at https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView) is using super() - Method which does not take HashMaps.

**Code**

```
public RoomAdapter(Context context, HashMap<UUID, Room> room) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_item_room, room.values());
}
```

I am at the beginners stage for Java, so I don't really know what I have to look for. I tried converting the collection received when I call `room.values()` to an ArrayList which is what I used before I tried to use a HashMap.

Is there a decent way to just fix this problem at this position in the code or do I have to change my code and use a ArrayList for my `room`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is `HashMap#values()` does not return an `ArrayList`. It returns a `Collection<T>` object that contains all of the values in the `Map`. An `ArrayList<T>` is a `Collection<T>`, but a `Collection<T>` is not necessarily an `ArrayList<T>` so your adapter does not know what to do with the Collection.  It could be an `ArrayList`, it could be a `HashSet`, it could be a `Vector`, it could be a `LinkedBlockingQueue` or any of the number of objects that extend from `Collection`. It may in fact be a custom implementation that only the HashMap knows about. The point is that it doesn't matter what the underlying collection is, and the HashMap doesn't make any guarantees on what it will return, so that's the interface you're stuck with.

You can fix the code by copying the values in to an ArrayList like so:

```
super(context, R.layout.list_item_room, new ArrayList(room.values()));
```

However, because it is a HashMap **there is no guarantee that the order in which you put the items will be the same as the order you receive them**.
but the values will be in whatever arbitrary order the HashMap decides to put them in.

A more predictable HashMap implementation is the [LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) which may serve your purposes.

Comment: I just read about LinkedHashMap a couple of minutes ago and am about to read through the docs, this is very helpful. I was asking exactly because of the reason that there is no guarantee that the ArrayList will be instantiated correctly, thanks for the advice.

Comment: The ArrayList will be instantiated correctly; there's just no guarantee that the `Collection<T>`  returned by the call to `values()` will have elements in any order you care about.  The data structure you're getting the values from is, by nature, unordered.  The only way to access an element is via a key.  Therefore, when it gives you some `Collection<T>` that you want to turn into some concrete `List<T>` of either its values, keys, entries, whatever, it cannot prescribe an order.

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is that your superclass's constructor doesn't take a typed `Collection` instance (`Collection<Type>`) as a parameter, but will take a typed `List` instance (`List<Type>`), you can just do something like:

```
public RoomAdapter(Context context, HashMap<UUID, Room> room) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_item_room, new ArrayList<>(room.values()));
}
```

Here, all I've done is instantiate a new ArrayList inline and passed it as a parameter to the superclass's constructor.  One of ArrayList's constructors accepts a typed `Collection`, which is what you get when you call `room.values()`.

Comment: Whenever I use this method, I get this error: `android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class TextView` at line `convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_room, parent, false);`

Comment: That means fixing your previous issue has revealed another: an error in your layout XML at line #6.